# Xamarin Forms OnAppearing not working in Android anymore

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hey I have a Tabbed Page as the master page.

Tabbed Page contains page C.

page C is an empty Carousel Page which is populated under a specific condition, a condition which is checked in its OnAppearing() method.

Now Page C has 10 pages added to it by this line in Page C OnAppearing():

```
Children.Add(new PersonPage()) //run 10 times so Page C is now a carousel page with 10 pages
```

This is working.

Now I am trying to add more people as the user reaches the end of carousel page so I do this by adding more people when the user hits the 8th page in the carousel by calling this in PersonPage OnAppearing():

```
parent.Children.Add(new PersonPage()) //called another 10 times
```

This used to work but it is no longer working and I don't know why. I am basically calling the above line in the PersonPage() OnAppearing() method which checks a flag and according to that calls the above line. This used to add another 10 pages to the carousel when the user reaches close to the end of it but now it does not.

It is because the OnAppearing() in PersonPage is not being fired. I have confirmed this by trying to display an alert in the OnAppearing method which does not fire anymore when swiping through the carousel.

Basically, I am trying to create an infinitely scrollable carousel by adding new pages as the user reaches the end of the carousel. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you not doing this in the constructor?

Comment: I'll try doing that.

Comment: Which part exactly do you think I should put in the constructor though?

Comment: Show me your PersonPage.cs please

Comment: Here you go: https://gist.github.com/Dobermensch I've added both PeoplePage and PersonPage

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at it?

Comment: Not actually give me sometime and i will let you know